# select name from different table based on id in dynamic stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i have a stored procedure in which i have to find out user Firstname and last name from [User] Table as Username based on the OrderInfo table's CustomerUserId As LoanOfficer and AffiliateId As Affiliate in select statement , i am stuck how to do that in a dynamic query.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GenerateReportList]
@pFromDate datetime=null,
@pToDate datetime=null,
@pAffiliateId int=null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)

    SET @SQLQuery ='
SELECT  
        OrderInfoId,
        BorrowerFirstName As ConsumerFirstName,
        BorrowerLastName As ConsumerLastName,
        RequestedURL,
        Requests,
        here i have to  display CustomeruserId As Loan officer
        o.CustomerUserID As Loan Officer,
        //what i am doing 
        u.FirstName +'' ''+ u.LastName As LoanOfficer, 
        // here i have to display affiliateId As Affiliate but can not able to implement 
      o.AffiliateId As Affiliate,


        o.RequestDateTime As DateOfTransaction,
        o.RequestIPAddress As OriginatingIPAddress, 
        o.Requests As Status
from orderInfo o 
inner join [User] u on o.AffiliateId = u.UserId'

if(@pFromDate != '' OR @pFromDate !=null)
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' and o.RequestDateTime >= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@pFromDate) +  ''''
END

if(@pToDate != '' OR @pToDate !=null)
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' and o.RequestDateTime <= ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@pToDate) + ''''

END

if(@pAffiliateId != '' OR @pAffiliateId !=null)
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery += ' and o.AffiliateId = ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25),@pAffiliateId) +  ''''
END
SET @SQLQuery += '
GROUP BY 
    OrderInfoId,
    BorrowerFirstName,
    BorrowerLastName, 
    RequestedURL,
    Requests,
    CustomerUserID,
    o.RequestDateTime,
    o.RequestIPAddress, 
    o.Requests,
    u.FirstName,
    u.LastName'

     EXEC (@SQLQuery) 
    --PRINT (@SQLQuery) 
END

Table User      OrderInfo           what i want to achieve

UserId,         OrderInfoId,          OrderInfoId,
FirstName,      CutomerUserId,        CustomerUserId As Loan Officer,
LastName,       AffiliateId           AffiliateId As Affiliate
Accountype
```

in this customeruserid and affiliate id both are userid.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with that Stored Procedure?

Comment: What is your problem? why can't you add "o.AffilateId as Affilate" ?

Comment: @mxix no its fine what i can not able to do is finding the name of user based on their id

Comment: @ElishevaWasserman yeah i have done that, and updated my question but i have to find their name based on the AffiliateId

Comment: Is there any particular reason why this is written in dynamic SQL? It can be simplified without it and may help you? Also, are Affiliate details in a separate table?

Comment: You can do almost everything in dynamic sql, please specify the fields you need , and from which table.  details of you table structure will be helpful

Comment: @ElishevaWasserman i have updated my question , have alook

Comment: Do you have another table?

Comment: @ElishevaWasserman no only these two tables

Comment: You need to show this way: customerId, customerName (base on customerId field) , userId, username (base od affilatId) ?

Comment: @sarin no not any particular reason, useing it for searching so ..

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstood your question..

```
SET @SQLQuery ='
SELECT  
    OrderInfoId,
    BorrowerFirstName As ConsumerFirstName,
    BorrowerLastName As ConsumerLastName,
    RequestedURL,
    Requests,
    here i have to  display CustomeruserId As Loan officer
    o.CustomerUserID As Loan Officer,
    //what i am doing 
    u.FirstName +'' ''+ u.LastName As LoanOfficer, 
    // here i have to display affiliateId As Affiliate but can not able to implement 
    o.AffiliateId As Affiliate,
    u2.FirstName+'' '' +u2.LastName as CustomerName

    o.RequestDateTime As DateOfTransaction,
    o.RequestIPAddress As OriginatingIPAddress, 
    o.Requests As Status
from orderInfo o 
inner join [User] u on o.AffiliateId = u.UserId
inner join [User] u2  on o.CustomerUserID =u2.UserID'
```

Comment: i have tried this before but when doing this i am not getting the proper result, what i am getting right now `inner join [User] u on o.CustomerUserId = u.UserId
LEFT JOIN [User] af on o.AffiliateId = af.UserId'` like thiis

Comment: So you have the solution, yes?